# Can I embed a Facebook connect app in a hosted (3rd-party) site?

Tags: flash, facebook, embed

We are writing a new social app that connects to FB using FB connect (actually, it's in Flash so we're using the FB AS3 SDK, which uses the FB Javascript API under the hood AFAIK).

When the flash app is served from our site - it works fine.
But when we try to embed it in a 3rd party site (using an Iframe that points to our site) the following happens: when we try to perform a login to FB using the AS3 function Facebook.login(onLogin, opts), a small browser-based login to FB pop-up comes up, but it has the following error first:

*Invalid Argument
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.*

Is there a way to solve this issue? Or is it possible that FB don't support FB connect apps that are embedded in 3rd party sites?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the container site (3rd party) url doesn't match the "site URL" you originally provide in the app's configuration. First you need to double check the AppID is correct. Second goto https://www.facebook.com/developers/, locate your app on the right sidebar. Find the link "Edit Settings" on the app's dashboard, click the "Web Site" tab on the left, change the Site URL and Site Domain to the 3rd party site.